# WCF: Nested DataContract Values are null

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am writing a WCF service that accepts XML data. However when I consume the service, the parameters it receives have null value.

Here's my service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ECardPaymentModel))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TransactionInformation))]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ECardPayment")]
        string ECardPayment(ECardPaymentModel Payment);
```

The Data Contracts:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Payment", Namespace = "")]
    [Serializable]
    public class ECardPaymentModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "TransactionInfo")]
        public TransactionInformation TransactionInfo { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "TransactionInfo")]
    public class TransactionInformation
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "transid")]
        public string TransID { get; set; }
    }
```

The XML that I use to call the service:

```
<Payment>
    <TransactionInfo>
           <customer>HD000083</customer>
           <transid>1001</transid>
    </TransactionInfo>
</Payment>
```

However, when the values I receive for `Payment.TransactionInfo.Customer` and `Payment.TransactionInfo.TransID` are both null.

I don't know where I am wrong. Because when I use flat objects, like

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Payment")]
    public class ECardPaymentModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "transid")]
        public string TransID { get; set; }
    }
```

And XML as,

```
<Payment>
           <customer>HD000083</customer>
           <transid>1001</transid>
</Payment>
```

I receive correct values for `Payment.Customer` and `Payment.TransID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `TransactionInformation` has a default xml namespace but you don't pass it for `customer` and `transid`.

You should try to remove the default namespace by setting `DataContract(..., Namespace = "")` on `TransactionInformation` class like you did it `ECardPaymentModel` class.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add Namespace = "" in DataContract for TransactionInformation. Let me know if that doesn't work.